# find a value from loop value and compare

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a list of executable names inside a textfile called `b.txt`, eg:

```
notepad.exe, chrome.exe
```

I need to compare them to the current process name, then do something if the application is a match:

```
    DWORD aProcesses[1024], cbNeeded, cProcesses;
    unsigned int i;

    EnumProcesses(aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded);

    cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);

    for (i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++)
    {
        if (aProcesses[i] != 0)
        {
            DWORD processID = aProcesses[i];
            wchar_t szProcessName[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("<unknown>");
            HMODULE hMod;
            DWORD cbNeeded;


            HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
                PROCESS_VM_READ,
                FALSE, processID);
            if (EnumProcessModules(hProcess, &hMod, sizeof(hMod),
                &cbNeeded))
            {
                GetModuleBaseName(hProcess, hMod, szProcessName,
                    sizeof(szProcessName) / sizeof(TCHAR));

                _wcslwr_s(szProcessName, wcslen(szProcessName) + 1);

                FILE *pFile;
                wchar_t *file = L"c:\\b.txt";
                wchar_t line[100][44];
                unsigned int i = 0;
                if (_wfopen_s(&pFile, file, L"r, ccs = UNICODE") == 0)
                {
                    while (fgetws(line[i], 100, pFile))
                    {
                        i++;
                    }
                }

                if (line[i] == szProcessName)
                {
                    cout << szProcessName + "It's Found";
                }

            }


        }
    }
```

I don't know why this code is not working. If I test each by `std::wcout` it outputs correctly, but the compare always fails.

Comment: Your code has lots of problems but fundamentally your test is in the wrong place; it needs to be inside the while loop.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Yeah, i realize that. can u fix it. so i can learn from that. thx

Comment: You read the file each time when you have a process to check. Why? Read the file at the start of the program into a set (you may ignore the case). Than just check if the filename is in the set...

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
if (line[i] == szProcessName)
```

Only compares the *addresses* of the two strings, which of course are different.  You want to compare the *contents* of these addresses.  Try using `wcsncmp()` instead:

```
if (wcsncmp(line[I], szProcessName, 44) == 0)
```